# If statement with 3 conditions SQL

Tags: sql, if-statement

I am trying to do an IF statement in SQL with 3 conditions but when I try to display the message, it displays all 3 messages. How can I end the if statement once one of these conditions is true?

```
IF( @QuantiteStock > 100) 
    SET @QuantiteStock = @QuantiteStock;
    PRINT  @NomProduit + ' n`a pas été touché.' ;


IF(@QuantiteStock  >= 10 AND @QuantiteStock <= 100) 
    SET @QuantiteStock  = @QuantiteStock *1.25;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@QuantiteStock) ;



    IF( @QuantiteStock < 10) 
        SET @QuantiteStock = 50;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à 50' ;
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more than one line you must use `begin` / `end` else everything after the first line is not conditional.

```
IF( @QuantiteStock > 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = @QuantiteStock;
    PRINT  @NomProduit + ' n`a pas été touché.' ;
END
```

So:

```
IF( @QuantiteStock > 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = @QuantiteStock;
    PRINT  @NomProduit + ' n`a pas été touché.' ;
END 
ELSE IF (...) BEGIN
    ...
END
ELSE BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much. I feel retarded for not putting the BEGIN after the IF statement.

Answer (score 0):

On its own [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms182717.aspx) applies only to the next statement, do this instead,

```
IF( @QuantiteStock > 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = @QuantiteStock;
    PRINT  @NomProduit + ' n`a pas été touché.';
END

IF(@QuantiteStock  >= 10 AND @QuantiteStock <= 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock  = @QuantiteStock *1.25;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à '
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@QuantiteStock);
END

IF( @QuantiteStock < 10) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = 50;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à 50';
END
```

The [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms182717.aspx) only applies to the next block or group. If you don't group statements with [`BEGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190487.aspx) and [`END`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190487.aspx) then they will each be separate blocks or groups.

[`BEGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190487.aspx) and [`END`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms190487.aspx) group the statements between them into a block.

---

Since your conditions are mutually exclusive you can chain them to avoid unnecessary processing.

```
IF( @QuantiteStock > 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = @QuantiteStock;
    PRINT  @NomProduit + ' n`a pas été touché.';
END
ELSE IF(@QuantiteStock  >= 10 AND @QuantiteStock <= 100) BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock  = @QuantiteStock *1.25;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à '
            + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@QuantiteStock);
END ELSE BEGIN
    SET @QuantiteStock = 50;
    PRINT @NomProduit + ' a été augmenté à 50';
END
```